# xelatex stop running with no error raised

Tags: centos, latex, xelatex

I run my tex file on CentOS7 using xelatex. I can see its progress in `top` but seems it stopped runnning with no error raised. And the final sentence on screen is:

`(/project/RD/transcriptome/software/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)`

Then it stopped here, no more running record on screen.
And if I press `Ctrl+C` to stop, it shows like this:

```
! Interruption. 
__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w ..._group:nTF {#1
                                                  }{__kernel_file_name_expan...
l.78 \end{titlepage}

?
```

tex scripts near line 78 is like this:

```
\begin{document}
% 封面设置
\begin{titlepage}
    % 封面图
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.2}{titlepages.png}

    \heiti
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{90pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Company Name}\\
        \vspace*{20pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Report Name}\\
        \vspace*{200pt}
    \end{center}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \zihao{-3} Series Number：& 00000000 \\
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Project Type：& 转录组 \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Customer Name：& XXX \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Customer Company：& XXXX \\
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Sample Number：& 40 \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Report Date：& \today \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{titlepage} % Here is line 78.
```

And I don't know why it stopped but no error raised, and did it really stop? I can still see its progress in `top` and its status is 'R'.

if any error is found, please tell me! Thanks!! :)

I have updated a sample here.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{ctex} % 编译中文
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % 这个包用来调整纸张大小和页边距
\geometry{left=2.0cm,top=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage{setspace} % 设置行距
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} % 设置首行缩进

% 字体相关
\usepackage{fontspec} % 用于设置英文字体
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % 用于设置中文字体
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun-Regular}
\setCJKsansfont{Heiti-Light}

% 图表相关
\usepackage{graphicx} % 插入图片
\usepackage{caption} % 插入图片标题
\usepackage{wallpaper} % 添加背景图
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% 页眉页脚
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhead{} % 初始化页眉
\rhead{\bfseries Right head od this page}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{anyPicture.png}} % Any picture here, just for test.
% \fancyfoot{} % 初始化页脚
\cfoot{page foot text here}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
% 封面设置
\begin{titlepage}
    % 封面图
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.2}{anyCoverPic.png} % You can put any picture here as a cover.
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{90pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Title}\\
        \vspace*{20pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{subtitle}\\
        \vspace*{200pt}
    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\section{Part1 -A sample}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
Here is the test text.Just for test.
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz OK, I have updated one.

Comment: Other than not having the fonts, your document compiles fine if I replace the images with some examples. Can you a) test with images without underscores in their name and b) add your .log file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have updated the test tex, but the log file is too long to upload. Could I sent it to you by any other ways?